# Gravitational wave Riemann tensor in the source gauge discrepancy

Tags: general-relativity, waves, gauge-theory, gravitational-waves, gauge-invariance

In many text books such as Gravitational waves volume 1 by Maggoire and General relativity by Hobson the solution to linearised Einstien field equations can be computed in the far-field using the standard greens functions method.

$$
 \bar{h}^{\mu \nu} = -\frac{4G}{c^4} \int_\mathcal{V} \frac{T^{\mu \nu}(t-\frac{|x-x'|}{c}, x')}{|x-x'|} d^3x' 
$$

For a binary system composed of non-relativistic point particles of mass M in the center-momentum frame have a stress energy tensor is defined by:

$$
T^{\mu \nu} = \rho(x-x_0(t))U^{\mu}U^{\nu}
$$

Where:

$$x^{A}_0 = (a\cos(\omega t),a\sin(\omega t),0)$$

$$x^{B}_0 = (-a\cos(\omega t),-a\sin(\omega t),0)$$

$$\rho(x-x_0(t)) = M[\delta(x^1-a\cos(\omega t))\delta(x^2-a\sin(\omega t))+\delta(x^1+a\cos(\omega t))\delta(x^2+a\sin(\omega t))] $$

For such a system the metric reads:

$$\bar{h}^{00} =  \frac{-4MG}{c^2 r}$$
$$,\bar{h}^{i0} = 0$$

$$\bar{h}^{11} = -\bar{h}^{22} = \frac{8MGa^2\omega^2}{c^4 r}\cos(2\omega [t-r/c])$$

$$\bar{h}^{12} = \bar{h}^{21} = \frac{8MGa^2\omega^2}{c^4 r}\sin(2\omega [t-r/c])$$

And all other components are zero. This solution can be projected into the Transverse traceless gauge via appropriate guage transformations or via the Lambda tensor.

$$
 h_{i j}^{TT} =  \Lambda (\hat{n})_{ij,kl} \bar{h}^{k l}
$$

Where:

$$
\Lambda_{ij,kl}(\hat{n}) = P_{ik}P_{jl}-P_{ij}P_{kl} 
$$

$$
P_{ij} = \delta_{ij}-n_in_j
$$

Projecting along the x-direction the metric reads.

$$h^{00}_{TT} =0 $$

$$h^{i0}_{TT} =0$$

$$ h^{22}_{TT} = -\frac{4MGa^2\omega^2}{c^4 r}\cos(2\omega [t-r/c]) $$

$$h^{33}_{TT} = \frac{4MGa^2\omega^2}{c^4 r}\cos(2\omega [t-r/c]) $$

All other components are zero. The Riemann tensor is given by:

$$
R_{\mu \nu \sigma \rho} = \frac{1}{2}( \partial_{\nu} \partial_{\sigma}h_{\mu \rho} +   \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\rho}h_{\nu \sigma}-\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\sigma}h_{\nu \rho}-\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\rho}h_{\mu \sigma})
$$

Computing the $R_{0101}$ component of the Riemann tensor for the centre-momentum frame and TT-gauge we get:

$$
R_{0101} = -\frac{1}{2c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 t} \bar{h}_{11}(r,t) 
$$
$$; r=x$$

$$
R_{0101}^{TT} = 0 
$$

The Riemann tensor should be gauge invariant so shouldn't the the green's function solution give the same answer ?